# How can I improve this neural net over MNIST?

Tags: java, algorithm, neural-network, backpropagation, mnist

I wrote a vanilla neural net for a project, and trained it on the famous MNIST data set. It gets about 85% accuracy and I was wondering why this is so much lower than the 95.3% success rate achieved by a neural net described on the MNIST website which on paper should be similar to mine.

More details about by neural net:

-The input is the 784 greyscale values (0-255) of each pixel in the 28x28 image

-It has layer sizes 784-256-10 plus a bias node with a fixed value of one connected to all the hidden and output nodes.

-It uses the sigmoid activation function

-The error of an output node is defined as the difference between it's value and the expected value squared.

-The neural network is trained via gradient descent across each of the 60,000 training cases once per iteration of the training algorithm.

-Usually this converges after about 15 iterations to a accurate classification percentage across the test cases of about 84%-88%.

-Despite the fact that all the literature I've read suggests it is necessary, the neural net performs worse when I have the bias node versus when I comment it out (I might be doing it wrong, lmk).

-Test and training cases are stored as objects which hold the values and the expected output in an array of all the cases.

Here is the main operative code of the program:

The initialization of the structure

```
   /**
   * A method to initialize the structure of the neural net
   * It adds a node for every input location needed, then it adds the hidden layer
   * connects the hidden layer to the input layer, makes the output layer, and connects the output layer 
   * to the hidden layer 
   */
   public void initializeStructure()
   {
      for(int ii = 0; ii < numInputs; ii++)
      {
         inputLayer.add(new Node());
      }   
      // add an extra node to the input layer. This node has a default value of one, so 
      // it acts like a bias to every node it is connected to (the bias has the magnitude of the weight)
      // this means that the only thing we need to edit are weights(including these ones), not values
      Node bias = new Node();
      bias.value = 1.0;
      inputLayer.add(bias);   
      for(int ii = 0; ii < layerSize; ii++)
      {
         Node currentNode = new Node();
         for(Node n : inputLayer)
         {                              
            currentNode.connections.add(new Connection(numInputs,n,currentNode,false));
         }         
         hiddenLayer.add(currentNode);
      }  
      for(int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
      {
         Node output = new Node();
         for(Node n : hiddenLayer)
         {
            output.connections.add(new Connection(numInputs,n,output,true)); 
         }     
         output.connections.add(new Connection(numInputs,bias,output,true));     
         outputLayer.add(output);
      }      
   }
```

The training algorithm

```
   public void train()
   {
      for(InputCase current : trainCases)
      {
         int[] expected  = new int[10];
         for(int jj = 0; jj < expected.length; jj++)
         {
            if(jj == current.expectedOutput)
               expected[jj] = 1;
            else
               expected[jj] = 0;
         }
         for(int jj = 0; jj < current.values.length; jj++)
         {
         inputLayer.get(jj).value = current.values[jj];
         }
         run();
         double sum = 0;
         for(int ii = 0; ii < outputLayer.size(); ii++)
         {
            Node n = outputLayer.get(ii);
            for(Connection c : n.connections)
            {
               c.weight -= learningRate * c.origin.value * c.destination.value * (1-c.destination.value) * (c.destination.value - expected[ii]);
               sum += c.destination.value * (1-c.destination.value) * (c.destination.value - expected[ii]) * c.weight;
            }
         }
         for(Node n : hiddenLayer)
         {
            for(Connection c : n.connections)
            {
               c.weight -= learningRate * c.origin.value * c.destination.value * (1-c.destination.value) * sum;
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

If you have any more questions, or want/need to see more code, just say!

Comment: It appears the error and weight updates occur at the same time. Try calculating the error for all layers, then go back and update the weights for each layer.

Comment: @AndrewS So the problem is that the adjustments in the hidden layer are affected by the adjustments made in the already made in the output layer? I assumed since the learning rate is fairly low that this wouldn't really matter, but i'll change it and see how that affects things. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewS I changed it and saw no real change in results, having tested it three times, It takes about two hours per test :( Any other Ideas?

Comment: The code is not complete so it's somewhat difficult to follow, but I'd suggest to look at how the error is calculated for each layer.  Make sure those formulas are correct.  In particular, the use of `sum` (the same value) in the hidden layer doesn't appear accurate.